# Number of Head-Tail in N independent coin flips

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value, independence

Consider a sequence of independent tosses of a biased coin at times $t = 0, 1, 2, . . .$. On each toss,
the probability of a ’head’ is $p$, and the probability of a ’tail’ is $1 − p$. A reward of one unit is
given each time that a ’tail’ follows immediately after a ’head.’ Let R be the total reward paid
in times $1, 2, . . . , n$. Find $E[R]$ and $var(R)$.

In the answer, it states that we can think of each $I_k$ as the indicator variable for the reward at time $k$ where $k<n$.  Then we can sum the $\sum_{k=1}^nE[I_k]$, where each $E[I_k] = p(1-p)$.

This partly makes sense to me because the chance of a tail and given that tail that there is a head in front of it is $p(1-p)$.  However I'm having some trouble understanding how linearity of expectation works here. If we consider the case where $n=3$, if $P(I_3 = 1 | I_2 = 1) = 0$ so I don't intuitively understand how we can just add the expectations, because $E[I_3]$ would be less than $p(1-p)$?.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: How do you derive the "because" in your last line?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.  I just thought intuitively $E[I_3]$ would be lower because it is dependent on $I_2$, I'm not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: One way to wrap your head around it is to tabulate all possible values of the first three or four tosses and look at the corresponding values of $I_2$ and $I_3.$ In fact, the toss at $t=0$ doesn't matter, so you only need a table of what occurs at times $t=1,2,3.$ I see two cases where $I_2=1;$ namely, HTT and HTH. Similarly there are only two cases where $I_3=1:$ THT and HHT. Notice that to find the expectations you don't need to know anything about how these events are related: you just have to know their frequencies.